# Disable collectionView userinteraction or scrolling in Custom cell Class

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` in root view.

`UICollectionView` has a custom cell named `HomeCell`.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HomeCell
```

in HomeCell I add bgView and title like this:

**HomeCell class:**

```
class HomeCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var bgView = UIView()
var title = UILabel()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    bgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
    bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

    title.text = "Test"
    title.textAlignment = .center
    title.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 210, width: 200, height: 40)
    title.textColor = .black

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTapCollapse(_:)))
    bgView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    self.addSubview(bgView)
    self.addSubview(title)
}

@objc func handleTapCollapse(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("disabled")
    // her I want to disable my collectionView

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
 }
```

I want when I touch my bgView disable `UICollectionView` scrolling.

I tried in `didSelectItemAt`, But it didn't work.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 1 {
        animateCamerCell()
    }
}
```

Is it possible? If not what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: yes it is possible `collectionview.isScrollEnabled = false`

Comment: @RahulGUsai not working in func handleTapCollapse.

Comment: you can add protocol to transfer your touch event to controller

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without taking any `protocol`.

You can take `weak` var of current `UICollectionview`, And in `handleTapCollapse function` you can disable scrolling.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HomeCell
    cell.collectionView = collectionView
}
```

And in `HomeCell`:

```
class HomeCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    weak var collectionView:UICollectionView?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }
    @objc func handleTapCollapse(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("disabled")
        collectionView?.isScrollEnabled = false
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first make protocol in your cell like this

```
protocol touchDelegate:class {
func DidTap(OnView view:UIView,with tap:UITapGestureRecognizer)
}

class HomeCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var bgView = UIView()
var title = UILabel()

weak var delegate:touchDelegate? 

override init(frame: CGRect) {
super.init(frame: frame)

bgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

title.text = "Test"
title.font = UIFont(name: "IRANSansFaNum", size: 18)
title.textAlignment = .center
title.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 210, width: 200, height: 40)
title.textColor = .black

let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTapCollapse(_:)))
bgView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

self.addSubview(bgView)
self.addSubview(title)
}

@objc func handleTapCollapse(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

print("disabled")
delegate?.DidTap(OnView: tap.view, with:sender)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

now got to your controller coonfirm to protocol

```
class yourcontroller:UIViewController, touchDelegate{
}
```

now make changes in your datasource method like

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! HomeCell
    cell.delegate = self
}
```

and implement delegate method in your controller

```
func DidTap(OnView view:UIView,with tap:UITapGestureRecognizer){
   self.yourcollectionviewVariable.isScrollEnabled = false
}
```